# Disable modal in kendo UI

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

My window is like this

```
$("#dialog").kendoWindow({
    position: {
        top: "100px",
        left: "400px"
    },
    height: "200px",
    width: "300px",
    title: "Upload File",

    modal: true,
    resizeable: false,


    close: {
        visible: false
    }
}).data("kendoWindow");
```

I have one cancel button

```
<button class="k-button" id="btnCancel" style="width: 125px" onclick="onCancelClick()">Cancel</button>
```

in this function i m closing window

```
function onCancelClick() {
    $("#dialog").kendoWindow();
    var dialog = $("#dialog").data("kendoWindow");
    dialog.close();
}
```

here I want to disable modal

Comment: This k-button is it outside or inside the modal?

Comment: Kendo UI `window` does not have a property called `close`. It needs to be defined as a function an it will be invoked when closing the window. There is `close` property but inside `animation` but it has no (afaik) `visible` member.

Comment: What is what you are actually trying to get? A modal window and a button outside the window that is clickable despite of the window being modal...?

Comment: I want one cancel button on kendo window which will work same as close btn of window and also will close modal after clicking it